# How to evaluate text formatting within a kable table?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, tidyverse

I have a variable containing an ANOVA result that (for the sake of simplicity) looks like this:

```
ANOVA_result <- "$F(1.92, 305.18) = 497.69$, $\\mathit{MSE} = 0.30$, $p < .001$, $\\hat{\\eta}^2_G = .543$"
```

I call this variable in-text in my rMarkdown document using:

```
The results of my ANOVA: `r ANOVA_result`
```

When knitting to PDF, this gives me the following (desired) output with all the correct formatting:

```
The results of my ANOVA:  (1.92, 305.18) = 497.69, MSE = 0.30,  < .001, ̂ = .543
```

My question is: **how do I get this desired output in a kable table?**

If I put the variable into a df, and call that with kable...

```
ANOVA_table <- tribble(
  ~"", ~"ANOVA result",
  "Variable", ANOVA_result)

ANOVA.table %>%
  kable("latex")
```

...it does not evaluate the formatting:

```
-----------------------------
           ANOVA result
-----------------------------
Variable   $F(1.92, 305.18) = 497.69$, $\mathit{MSE} = 0.30$, $p < .001$, $\hat{\eta}^2_G = .543$
-----------------------------
```

The desired output would look like:

```
-----------------------------
           ANOVA result
-----------------------------
Variable    (1.92, 305.18) = 497.69, MSE = 0.30,  < .001, ̂ = .543
-----------------------------
```

Any guidance appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `escape = F` to the `kbl` function.

Here is your code in a simple `.Rmd` file:

````
---
title: "escape = F"
author: bttomio
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

## R Markdown

```{r image_graph}
library(kableExtra)
library(tibble)
library(tidyverse)

ANOVA_result <- "$F(1.92, 305.18) = 497.69$, $\\mathit{MSE} = 0.30$, $p < .001$, $\\hat{\\eta}^2_G = .543$"

ANOVA_table <- tribble(
  ~"", ~"ANOVA result",
  "Variable", ANOVA_result)

ANOVA_table %>%
  kable("latex", escape = F)
```
````

Output:

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Adding "escape = F" to my existing code did the job, many thanks :)